# Reshaping data frame and nb occurance

Tags: r

I've data as follow

```
mydata=structure(list(X = structure(c(6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
    "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), Sous_Categorie = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("o,y", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
    "Sous_Categorie"), row.names = c(NA, -86L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this : `cc=count(mydata, c("X", "Sous_Categorie"))` 
it gives me

```
    X Sous_Categorie freq
1   1              y    2
2   3              y    4
3   4              y    5
4   5              y   26
5   6            o,y    2
6   6              y   16
7   7            o,y    2
8   7              y    7
9   8            o,y    1
10  8              y    6
11  9              y    5
12 10            o,y    4
13 10              y    6
```

But I'm aiming to obtain out put as this : X is always from 1 to 12 even if there is no value, nb_freq is the occurence number in X

```
X        o,y       o
1        nb_freq  nb_freq
.
.
12       nb_freq  nb_freq
```

what is the simpliest way to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
     group_by(X, Sous_Categorie) %>%
     tally() %>% 
     spread(Sous_Categorie, n) %>%
     left_join(data_frame(X= factor(1:12)), .)
```

Comment: Almost what i'm looking for, thanks! but how to specify X from 1 to 12 even i've no values for 2 , 11 , 12  ?

Comment: @ranell Did you meant `mydata %>% group_by(X, Sous_Categorie) %>% tally() %>% spread(Sous_Categorie, n) %>% left_join(data_frame(X= factor(1:12)), .)`

Comment: Exactly, didn't think about using left join for this purpose. Thanks a lot !